# Tray icons - WIFI vs VPN icons

Tags: windows-10, vpn, icons, wifi-configuration

I noticed when connected to the internet via VPN, the desktop tray on my laptop shows one of two icons - see uploaded image. I get the WIFI icon and the VPN icon see images.  If I click on the WIFI icon when dispalyed, it says 'connected, secure' and if its the VPN image it says 'no internet' but both give me access to the internet and in both instances my separate VPN icon is green which is another indication I am connected to the internet.  The WIFI being displayed whilst my VPN is connected to the internet is a new thing so am unsure if this is secure, can anyone shed any light on why the WIFI icon is showing when the VPN is connected when I usually just get the Windows 10 VPN icon (the Laptop/desktop screen)?

Thanks

[WIFI vs VPN icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e43y.png)

Comment: “no internet” is displayed when a specific Microsoft domain cannot be reached. This would be normal while connected to a VPN

Comment: Specifically, the Network Connectivity Status Indicator contacts Microsoft servers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/ncsi/ncsi-frequently-asked-questions "The public NCSI probe servers formerly hosted by Azure Front Door are now being hosted by Akamai."